# True arithmetic is working properly, false is not displaying proper output

Tags: java, if-statement

I have been asked to create a program that requires the user purchasing glasses to provide a yes or no input to any additional accessories.  Though probably not the cleanest code ever, the true statements work properly, my "false" or else statements are displaying the wrong outputs.  I have tried nested ifs, else statements without specifying a false Boolean.  I am guessing my problem is with the way I have my integers declared and initialized.  Somewhere along the process the values are not being stored properly (if at all).  Forgive me if this seems like an extremely basic question, it's been a long time since I've had to code and it was visual basic at that, Java feels extremely foreign to me.  I should add, I'm not looking for solutions, just guidance.  Thank you in advance, I would normally just walk in during office hours but I'm currently deployed with dang near zero resources.

We are still early in the course, and I've considered the options that our professor may have wanted to see us use a do or while statement.  Unfortunately, any guidance has been fairly abstract (I'm aware this is likely done on purpose for freedom of development).

```
import java.util.Scanner;  //for Scanner

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Basic glasses = $25");
System.out.println("Premium?");

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String myInput = myScanner.next();
boolean isTrue = (myInput.equals("y"));
boolean isFalse = (myInput.equals("n"));

//declare int
int subTotal = 0;
double total = 0;
int tint = 10;
int polar = 20;
int base = 25;
int premium = 50;

double half = .50;

//premium price
if (isTrue) {
subTotal = base + premium;
System.out.println("$" + subTotal);
}
else if (isFalse) {
subTotal = subTotal + base;
System.out.println("$" + subTotal);
}

System.out.println("tint?");
myScanner.next();

//tint price
if(isTrue) {
subTotal = subTotal + tint;
System.out.println("$" + subTotal);
}
else if (isFalse) {
System.out.println("$" + subTotal);
}
System.out.println("polar?");
myScanner.next();

//polarization price
if (isTrue) {
subTotal = subTotal + polar;
System.out.println("$" + subTotal);
}
else if (isFalse) {
System.out.println("$" + subTotal);
}

System.out.println("Second pair?");
myScanner.next();

//Second pair
if (isTrue) {
total = subTotal + (subTotal * half);
System.out.println("$" + total);
}
else {
total = subTotal;
System.out.println("$" + total);
}
myScanner.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Answer (score 0):

So the booleans are what you think, but you need to update them to reflect the next response from the user as you go along. So after your prompts (for tint and beyond) where you say just `myScanner.next()` you need to say:

```
myInput = myScanner.next();
isTrue = (myInput.equals("y"));
isFalse = (myInput.equals("n"));
```

Comment: This did the trick, it seems like I was on the right track just not all the way there.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the string `myInput` and boolean variables `isTrue` and `isFalse` after every option causing whatever the user enters for the options after premium to not be accurately accounted for since it is using the boolean values from the FIRST "premium" option every time.

I haven't written the code for you since you specifically said not to give solutions just guidance.

Comment: Thank you for your input and time, it's greatly appreciated!